# Calculating a "max support flux vector sequence"

Tags: algorithms, notation, vectors, definition, chemistry

### Tl;dr: what is a max support flux vector sequence?

In **[a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04125)** (arXiv link; full citation below) on continuous chemical reaction networks (CCRNs)$^1$ it discusses an algorithm for reaching different states using various chemical reactions. I have some questions about a line of the algorithm and what it means given the authors' notation.

### Preliminaries

The paper defines  a set of species $\Lambda$ (which is finite) and a set of reactions over $\Lambda$ as $R$, which is also finite. A reaction is an element $\rho =(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{p})\in\mathbb{N}^\Lambda\times\mathbb{N}^\Lambda$ ($\mathbb{N}$ being the set of all natural numbers); $\rho$ as a reaction seems to be $\in R$ (which makes sense) as I understand the paper. Here $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ represent the stoichometry of the reactants and products. A state of a CCRN is defined as a vector $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^\Lambda_{\geq 0}$ specifying a non-negative concentration of each species.

A flux vector is also defined, as a vector $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^R_{\geq 0}$ (the paper also defines a support of a flux vector and whether or not a flux vector is applicable at a state $\mathbf{c}$). Finally, a flux vector sequence $\mathbf{U}$ is defined as a tuple of flux vectors.

### Algorithm

The algorithm takes the input of $\Lambda$ (and by consequence $R$) as well as the starting state of the system $\mathbf{c}$ and the desired ending state of the system $\mathbf{d}$. The relevant portions of the algorithm (not exactly quoted) are as follows (the numbers at the left signify the line numbers as listed in the paper):

2: for each reaction $\rho\in R$
3: if a vector $F_\rho\in\mathbb{Q}^R_{\geq 0}$ such that certain conditions are true compute it
4: if no such vector exists, eliminate $\rho$ from $R$
5: end for
8: for each $\rho\in R$ set $S(\rho) = \frac{1}{|R|}\sum^\limits{|R|}_\limits{i=1}F_i(\rho)$
9: compute $\epsilon = \frac{\text{min}\{S(\rho)\}_{\rho\in R}}{2}$
10: compute the max support flux vector sequence $\mathbf{U}_{\mathbf{c},\epsilon}$

### Question(s)

Nowhere in the paper does it say anything about a *max support* flux vector sequence - what does it mean by this, and how would one calculate it? I am also unsure what a flux vector or a flux vector sequence represents physically speaking - I understand most of the other concepts defined, but not these at all. Another related question can be found at [How do subscripts affect this calculation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338796/how-do-subscripts-affect-this-calculation) (I was advised to split the two questions up).

---

$^1$*Case, Adam; Lutz, Jack H.; Stull, D.M.*, [**Reachability problems for continuous chemical reaction networks**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-41312-9_1),  [ZBL06630580](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06630580).